# In Dart, how can copy/clone a 2D list?

Tags: flutter, dart, copy, clone

I have 2 two dimensional lists declared as following, what is the correct and fast way to copy/clone a 2 dimensional list (I to N) in Dart?

```
List<List<double>>? I = List.generate(
        3, (i) => List.generate(1000 * 1000, (j) => 0.0, growable: false),
        growable: false);
 List<List<double>>? N = List.generate(
        3, (i) => List.generate(1000 * 1000, (j) => 0.0, growable: false),
```

I can loop through each element and copy it but that's not the efficient way to do it.

```
for (int i = 0; i < I!.length; i++)
      for (int j = 0; j < I![i].length; j++) N![i][j] = I![i][j];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[List](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List-class.html)
List.copyRange(List target, int at, List source, [int? start, int? end])

list.setRange(int start, int end, Iterable iterable, [int skipCount = 0])

```
for (int i = 0; i < I!.length; i++)
    List.copyRange<int>(N![i], 0, I![i])
```

```
for (int i = 0; i < I!.length; i++)
    N![i].setRange<int>(0, N![i].length,I![i])
```

This will reset the item pointer

```
List.copyRange(N!,0, I!.map<List<int>>((item)=>item.toList()).toList());
```

Comment: Thanks Shirne. List.setRange works. However, I get "The argument type 'Iterable<List<double>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<List<double>>' when I tried with `List.copyRange(N!,0, I!.map<List<double>>((item)=>item.toList());`

Comment: I!.map( ... ).toList()

Comment: List.copyRange only receive List (but not iteriable), the List.map may return an Iteriable, you can call iteriable.toList to Conversion type

Answer (score 1):

Given a `List<List<double>>` named `original`, I would copy it with:

```dart
List<List<double>> copy = [for (var sublist in original) [...sublist]];
```

Note that this would create a new `List<List<double>>`; if you must mutate an existing one instead, then using `List.setRange` [as shirne suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69341104/) would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it:
N = I.map((e) => [...e]).toList();

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).